# No highlight colors after saving (default IDLE Editor)

Tags: python, python-3.x, editor, syntax-highlighting, python-idle

Python IDLE Editor doesn't seem to be working for me.
As can be seen in this picture, `if`, `'hello'` and `None` are all highlighted with different colors when the document is "untitled" (not saved) but as soon as i save the document the colors disapear as can be seen in the picture to the right. Changing custom highlighting doesn't have an effect.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You didn't save it as a `.py` file...

Answer (score 0):

OMG i'm so stupid. While saving i just selected .py without actually typing .py at the end of the file name.

Tried to figure the problem out 30 minutes before asking here then a few seconds after posting relized my mistake

Comment: Note that you should have included searching for the problem between trying to figure it out and asking here.

Comment: I actually did google for a solution but found nothing

Comment: SO has it own search bar with syntax  [tagname] search-term*.  It gets results on SO better than a normal Google search.  In particular, `[python-idle] highlight syntax` gets 18 results, with the linked duplicate 2nd.  You are allowed to delete your own question.